# installation page reload loop PrestaShop 1.7

Tags: prestashop

Fresh installation 1.7.3 from official site.

```
php 5.6, 7.1

index.php = 664

prestashop.zip = 666
```

Loading progress bar to 100% -> page reloads and beginning from top

if I manually unpacked zip - got error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Tools' not found in /home/comput/www/classes/PrestaShopAutoload.php on line 219
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not have enough inodes on FS, it's because my hoster has a quota on inodes. After increasing the quota, everything was installing without problems